How can I fireblock basement wall
I am finishing my basement. I am about to build my wall and wondering what is the easiest way to fireblock (to stop vertical movement of fire).
Options:

Use 1/2 inch drywall from sill plate to front of new wall stud. If I do this there will be a gap between sill plate and front edge of concrete blocks (basement exterior wall). How to fill this?
Fill the space between sill plate and new wood wall with fiberglass batting.

I prefer #2 but anyone done that and has pictures on what that should look like?
Here is what my wall looks like right now

